# Overall memory bytes limited?

Tags: quicktime, qtkit

I'm creating a video editing program with QTKit.

There is a sample program provided by apple here,
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/CreatingaQTKitStoporStillMotionApplication/CreatingaQTKitStoporStillMotionApplication.html

My test program is based on this program, but use

QTMovie *movie = [[[QTMovie alloc] initToWritableFile:@"foo.mov" error:nil] autorelease];

and

[movie updateMovieFile];

for saving memories.

If there are not so many frames, the program runs well. But with so many frames, the program begins to show

`QTKitServer(5618,0xa0924540) malloc: *** mmap(size=33554432) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

I checked memory leaks with Instruments,
[image]

but Live Bytes are not so big and found no memory leaks.
Overall Bytes is really big but is this a reason of this problem?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall bytes should not be a problem unless there is an unreported memory leak.

After some googling some people seem to get this problem when compiling for 32bit, what architecture are you compiling against?

Comment: I tried compiling for 32bit, and 64bit, and got the same error... hmmm :( Thanks for reply, anyway

Comment: Finally, I found the problem was at outside of the program itself. There are memory leaks in QTKit and we can't see memory leak via Instrument because it happens on QTKitServer process. Memory leaks were at -[QTKit frameAtTime:] api.

Comment: I see, you should make your own answer so you can close the issue :)

Comment: How did you overcome the leak in QTKitServer?